# publish json data to mqtt

Tags: esp8266, esp32, json, mqtt

I am trying to publish `JSON` data to mqtt with following code snippet

```
#include <Arduino_JSON.h>
JSONVar data;
data["temperature"] = temperature;
data["humidity"] = humidity;
data["pressure"] = pressure;
data["chipId"] = chipId;

String jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
client.publish("esp32/data", jsonString);
```

But getting following error

```
/home/ubuntu/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient/src/PubSubClient.h:144:12: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 2 provided
Multiple libraries were found for "PubSubClient.h"
 Used: /home/ubuntu/Arduino/libraries/PubSubClient
Multiple libraries were found for "Wire.h"
 Used: /home/ubuntu/.arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/1.0.4/libraries/Wire
Multiple libraries were found for "Adafruit_BME280.h"
 Used: /home/ubuntu/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_BME280_Library
Multiple libraries were found for "Adafruit_Sensor.h"
 Used: /home/ubuntu/Arduino/libraries/Adafruit_Unified_Sensor
Multiple libraries were found for "SPI.h"
 Used: /home/ubuntu/.arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/1.0.4/libraries/SPI
Multiple libraries were found for "Arduino_JSON.h"
 Used: /home/ubuntu/Arduino/libraries/Arduino_JSON
Multiple libraries were found for "WiFi.h"
 Used: /home/ubuntu/.arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/1.0.4/libraries/WiFi
 Not used: /opt/arduino-1.8.10/libraries/WiFi
exit status 1
no matching function for call to 'PubSubClient::publish(const char [11], String&)'
```

Whats is wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's your last error message?

```
no matching function for call to 'PubSubClient::publish(const char [11], String&)'
```

[Read the documentation](https://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/api.html#publish1) for the `publish()` method in `PubSubClient`:

> int publish (topic, payload)
>
> Publishes a string message to the specified topic.
>
> Parameters
>
> topic - the topic to publish to (const char[])
>
> payload - the message to publish (const char[])

Look at the parameters you're using. You're passing a `String` as `payload`. `publish()` expects `payload` to be a `char[]` (essentially the same thing as a `char*`) - a C language string. This is the error you're seeing.

[Read the documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) for `String`. How do you get a `char*` from a `String`? The `c_str()` method.

You need to change

```
client.publish("esp32/data", jsonString);
```

to

```
client.publish("esp32/data", jsonString.c_str());
```

As for your other warnings, it looks like your Arduino libraries are a mess with multiple conflicting libraries installed; if you want to get rid of the warnings, clean up your libraries.

Comment: is it possible to convert `json` to `char*` ?

Comment: @roy - I've given you the steps to do that in the answer. If you want to do it more directly, you're using the Arduino_JSON library. The declaration for the `stringily()` method is at https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Arduino_JSON/blob/master/src/JSON.h and it only shows a `String` as a return, so you cannot do it more directly using this library.

Comment: `Arduino_JSON` has this link https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Arduino_JSON, not much info here. Most of the example are based on `ArduinoJSON`.

Comment: My comment answered your question - I may have been editing it when you were replying. You can find the answer in the declaration of `stringify()` in`json.h`